# Creating a link to images code updated

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jquery code which can wrap an img tag with a link:

My code is like this and

http://prntscr.com/iuw6hc

I will paste my html here but basically it is a loop of many items showing within each col

```
<div class="car-item gray-bg text-center first" style="height: 357px;">        
        <div class="car-image">            
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http:///wp-content/uploads/2018/03/20180214_090633-265x190.jpg" alt="" width="265" height="190">            
            <div class="car-overlay-banner">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http:///cars/chevrolet-silverado-1500-lt-z71/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="View"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
```

i am trying like this

```
var wrapped = false;
    var original = $(".img-responsive");

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (!wrapped) {
            wrapped = true;
            var gURL = $('.car-overlay-banner').find('a').attr('href');
            $(".img-responsive").wrap("<a href=\"'+ gURL +'\"></a>");
        }
    });

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (wrapped) {
            wrapped = false;
            $(".img-responsive").parent().replaceWith(original);
        }
    });
```

trying to use a href of car overlay to apply to the image too,

updated to the code:

```
$('.car-image img').each(function() { // For each image
    var ax = $(this).parents('div.car-image').find('a:first'); // Find its associated anchor 
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + ax.attr('href') + '"></a>'); // And wrap the image
});
```

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you have two click functions for the same classname, that will have strange effects.  Also, instead of trying to wrap an anchor around it, just put a class name in your image in your html, and make .click events for those. In that event do whatever you need to do

Comment: please mark answer as correct if it helped you with your question. No other answers have been posted, it has received an upvote, and you haven't posted any follow up questions or comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make your html with a data attribute of the href url you want to visit

```
            <img class="img-responsive" data-img-url="http:///cars/chevrolet-silverado-1500-lt-z71/" src="http:///wp-content/uploads/2018/03/20180214_090633-265x190.jpg" alt="" width="265" height="190">
```

Then make your jquery use that url to go to that location:

```
$(".img-responsive").click(function(){
    var yourUrl = $(this).data('imgUrl');
    document.location.href = yourUrl;
});
```

of course if you can build the url at html design time, you might as well just wrap the image in the anchor tag in your html to begin with.  Without knowing more about why you're trying to solve the problem with javascript, this is the best I got for you.